# What is the name of the anime this pink-haired girl is from?

Tags: brynhildr-in-the-darkness

I saw this picture on facebook and I would like to know what anime she is from

[image: Pink-haired girl, subtitles read "You can do whatever you want with my body."]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is [Kazumi Schlierenzauer](http://myanimelist.net/character/92359/Kazumi_Schlierenzauer) from [Gokukoku no Brynhildr](http://myanimelist.net/anime/21431/Gokukoku_no_Brynhildr). This show is currently airing this season (Spring 2014).

[image]